# PHP, preg_match: How to get strings in between two chars like curly braces with sub markers wraped in curly braces inside?

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all, templating

If I have a string like below:

```
$str = "Some {translate:text} with some {if:{isCool}?{translate:cool}|{translate:uncool}} features";
```

... I would like to get the following result:

```
array (
  0 => 'translate:text',
  1 => 'if:{isCool}?{translate:cool}|{translate:uncool}',
)
```

I already have this function but i belive its possible to simplify it with preg_match(_all)?

```
define('STR_START','{');
define('STR_END','}');

function getMarkers($str, &$arr = array()) {
    if(strpos($str,STR_START)) {
        list($trash,$str) = explode(STR_START,$str, 2);
        unset($trash);

        $startPos = 0;
        $endPos = 0;
        do {
            $strStartPos = strpos($str,STR_START,$startPos);
            $strEndPos = strpos($str,STR_END,$endPos);
            $startPos = $strStartPos + 1;
            $endPos = $strEndPos + 1;
        } while($strStartPos !== false && $strStartPos < $strEndPos);

        $arr[] = substr($str,0,$strEndPos);
        getMarkers(substr($str,$strEndPos+1),$arr);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

I have tried the following but it dose not work that well with submarkers.

```
preg_match_all('/\{(.*?)\}/',"Some {translate:text} with some {if:{isCool}?{translate:cool}|{translate:uncool}} features", $matches);
var_export($matches[1]);

array (
  0 => 'translate:text',
  1 => 'if:{isCool',
  2 => 'translate:cool',
  3 => 'translate:uncool',
)
```

Is it possible to ajust the abowe mentioned pattern to get the right result?

```
array (
  0 => 'translate:text',
  1 => 'if:{isCool}?{translate:cool}|{translate:uncool}',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a recursive pattern, example:

```
$pattern = '~{((?>[^{}]++|(?R))*)}~';
```

Where `(?R)` stands for all the pattern (the whole pattern repeated inside itself)